# Failed to hide the cursor in Console?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw32

```
int main (void) 
{
 //Get a console handle
 HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();

 struct CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO
 {
  DWORD dwSize;
  BOOL bVisible;
 };
 struct CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO CURSOR;

 CURSOR.bVisible = FALSE;
 SetConsoleCursorInfo(myconsole, CURSOR);
}
```

I want to hide the cursor in Console, but failed.

What GCC-mingw32 reports are listed here:

```
error: request for member 'bVisible' in something not a structure or union
error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'SetConsoleCursorInfo'
```

Could  anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using a **type** as if it were an **object**. `CURSOR c; c.bVisible = FALSE;` is what you need. [`SetConsoleCursorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686019.aspx) also wants a **`HANDLE`** to the *console screen buffer*, not a `HWND` (a handle to the console window).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincon.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) 
{
 //Get a console handle
 HANDLE myconsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

/* It is already defined.
 struct CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO
 {
  DWORD dwSize;
  BOOL bVisible;
 };
*/
 //CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO is defined type.
 CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO CURSOR;

 BOOL result;

 CURSOR.dwSize = 1;
 CURSOR.bVisible = FALSE;
 result=SetConsoleCursorInfo(myconsole, &CURSOR);//second argument need pointer
 if(result){//success
   printf("test print\n");
   getch();//wait
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`#define STRICT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383681.aspx). It would have caught both your attempt to assign a `HANDLE` to a `HWND` and passing a `HWND` to a `HANDLE` argument. And fix the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a size to the CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO struct.  It doesn't work otherwise.

CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO CURSOR;

CURSOR.bVisible = FALSE;
CURSOR.dwSize = 1; /*This is what you left out*/

SetConsoleCursorInfo(StdHandle, &CURSOR);